# How can I use OpenSSL to encrypt a message using my public key and then decrypt it using my private key?

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key, private-key

Here is what I've tried:

**Encrypt message w/ my public key**

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -kfile key.pub -in message.txt -out message.enc
```

**Decrypt message using my private key**

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -in message.enc -pass file:mykey.pem
```

**Error from decryption**

```
bad decrypt
452:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:330:
```

Comment: `enc - symmetric cipher routines` so you should use `rsautl`

Answer (score 5):

This code works:

```
openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey key.pub -encrypt -in message.txt -out message.enc

openssl rsautl -inkey privkey.pem -decrypt -in message.enc -out message.dec
```

Comment: The problem with that is you can only use it to encrypt small messages. If you try to encrypt anything over the size of your key minus 11 bytes you'll get an error message like: rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size

Answer (score 1):

For use

> openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey key.pub -encrypt -in message.txt -out message.enc

You need define option -raw to ignore padding :)

> openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey key.pub -encrypt -in message.txt -out message.enc -raw

Answer (score 1):

`enc - symmetric cipher routines` so you should use `rsautl`

Correct solutions:

**On sender side**

1. Generate passphrase
2. Encrypt your message using `enc` with passphrase
3. Encrypt passphrase using `rsautl` with public key
4. Send encoded message and encoded passphrase

**On receiver side**

1. Decrypt passphrase using `rsautl` with private key
2. Decrypt message using `enc` with passphrase

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:password.txt -in message.txt -out message.enc
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pass file:password.txt -in message.enc -out message.dec
```

Where the first line of the file `password.txt` contains your password.

Comment: This method works fine using a simple password text file -- but I need to encrypt using my public key and decrypt using my private one.

Comment: This worked: 

openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey key.pub -encrypt -in message.txt -out message.enc
openssl rsautl -inkey privkey.pem -decrypt -in message.enc -out message.dec